# Child component not spanning full width in custom carousel

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, carousel

I want the carousel components to span full width so that when I click on next and  previous buttons the components come one by on in view but I am not able to make the child component span the parent div without using pixels for width. I don't want to use classes like w-[1000px] because the the responsiveness will be lost.

In these snippets I have used ReactJS, Tailwind CSS and framer-motion for animation. The problem is not with framer motion. The CSS is not working fine for some reason.

Here's the parent component snippet

```
function SDEInfo() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between gap-12 pt-[21px] pb-[65px] px-[30px] md:px-[65px]">
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setIndex((prev) => prev != 0 && --prev)}>
        <BsArrowLeftCircle className="text-3xl text-[#37ED81]" />
      </button>

      <div className="overflow-hidden w-[80vw]">
        <motion.div
          animate={{ x: `-${index * 100}%` }}
          className="flex items-center gap-10"
        >
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <SDEInfoCarouselComponent item={item} key={index} />
          ))}
        </motion.div>
      </div>

      <button type="button" onClick={() => setIndex((prev) => prev != data.length-1 && ++prev)}>
        <BsArrowRightCircle className="text-3xl text-[#37ED81]" />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the child component SDEInfoCarouselComponent snippet is as follows

```
function SDEInfoCarouselComponent({ item }) {
  const { theme } = useContext(UIContext);
  return (
    <div className="w-[100%]">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-20 items-center">
        <div className="lg:col-span-7">
          <h2 className="text-[24px] md:text-[30px] lg:text-[36px] font-medium leading-relaxed text-[#101010] dark:text-[#37ED81]">
            {item?.heading}
          </h2>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-10 w-full mt-20 lg:mt-32">
            {item?.info.map((point, index) => (
              <div
                className="flex gap-4 items-center text-[#101010] dark:text-white"
                key={index}
              >
                <BsPatchCheck className="text-2xl" />
                <p className="md:font-medium text-base md:text-lg w-full">
                  {point}
                </p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="lg:col-span-5">
          <h2 className={`${style.gradient_text} text-2xl font-medium`}>
            {item?.subHeading}
          </h2>
          <p className="text-[#101010] dark:text-white mt-10 md:text-xl font-normal dark:font-thin">
            {item?.desc}
          </p>
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <img
              src={theme === "light" ? item?.lightSVG : item?.darkSVG}
              className="mt-5"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Below is the screenshot of my output:

[image: screenshot of problem faced]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applying `flex-shrink: 0` to the root `<div>` of the `SDEInfoCarouselComponent` via the `shrink-0` class to override the default of `flex-shrink: 1`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex items-center justify-between gap-12 pt-[21px] pb-[65px] px-[30px] md:px-[65px]">
  <button type="button">
    <BsArrowLeftCircle class="text-3xl text-[#37ED81]">BsArrowLeftCircle</BsArrowLeftCircle>
  </button>

  <div class="overflow-hidden w-[80vw]">
    <div class="flex items-center gap-10">

      <div class="w-[100%] shrink-0">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-20 items-center">
          <div class="lg:col-span-7">
            <h2 class="text-[24px] md:text-[30px] lg:text-[36px] font-medium leading-relaxed text-[#101010] dark:text-[#37ED81]">
              {item?.heading}
            </h2>
            <div class="flex flex-col gap-10 w-full mt-20 lg:mt-32">
              <div class="flex gap-4 items-center text-[#101010] dark:text-white">
                <BsPatchCheck class="text-2xl" />
                <p class="md:font-medium text-base md:text-lg w-full">
                  {point}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="lg:col-span-5">
            <h2 class="text-2xl font-medium">
              {item?.subHeading}
            </h2>
            <p class="text-[#101010] dark:text-white mt-10 md:text-xl font-normal dark:font-thin">
              {item?.desc}
            </p>
            <div class="flex justify-center">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/48/48" class="mt-5" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="w-[100%] shrink-0">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-12 gap-20 items-center">
          <div class="lg:col-span-7">
            <h2 class="text-[24px] md:text-[30px] lg:text-[36px] font-medium leading-relaxed text-[#101010] dark:text-[#37ED81]">
              {item?.heading}
            </h2>
            <div class="flex flex-col gap-10 w-full mt-20 lg:mt-32">
              <div class="flex gap-4 items-center text-[#101010] dark:text-white">
                <BsPatchCheck class="text-2xl" />
                <p class="md:font-medium text-base md:text-lg w-full">
                  {point}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="lg:col-span-5">
            <h2 class="text-2xl font-medium">
              {item?.subHeading}
            </h2>
            <p class="text-[#101010] dark:text-white mt-10 md:text-xl font-normal dark:font-thin">
              {item?.desc}
            </p>
            <div class="flex justify-center">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/48/48" class="mt-5" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button">
    <BsArrowRightCircle class="text-3xl text-[#37ED81]">BsArrowRightCircle</BsArrowRightCircle>
  </button>
```